# JavaFX 8 Image load (Invalid URL or resource not found)

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-8

as said there [docs.oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) about Image class:

```
// load an image in background, displaying a placeholder while it's loading  
// (assuming there's an ImageView node somewhere displaying this image)  
// The image is located in default package of the classpath
Image image1 = new Image("/flower.png", true);
```

I shared my simple project at [github](https://github.com/aovchinn/JavaFXDemo), so you can easily access code.
and this is piece of my code:

```
splashScreen = new Image("/gravixsplash.png");
splashScreenBackplate = new ImageView();
splashScreenBackplate.setImage(splashScreen);

instructionLayer = new Image("/gravixinstructions.png");
splashScreenTextArea = new ImageView();
splashScreenTextArea.setImage(instructionLayer);
```

But this don't wanna work for me, I get this:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1081)

at (Image.java:1081) I find this:

```
if (resource == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid URL or resource not found");
}
```

I assume that my url(resource) is for some reason equal to null, but it didn't help me find the solution.

(Maybe somehow I need to turn on javaFX8, i suspect that intellijIDEA build javaFX2 project, I was searching for this in settings, but didn't find anything)

Comment: The images in your project aren't in the root of your class path, they are in `/ru/petrsu/javafxGame/`.  Did you try: `new Image("/ru/petrsu/javafxGame/gravixsplash.png")`

Comment: @jewelsea thx, all working now!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images in your project aren't in the root of your class path, they are in:

```
 /ru/petrsu/javafxGame/
```

So instead of:

```
new Image("/gravixsplash.png")
```

Use:

```
new Image("/ru/petrsu/javafxGame/gravixsplash.png")
```

From the [Image javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html):

> If the passed string is not a valid URL, but a path instead, the Image is searched on the classpath in that case.