# Relative URL not working in javafx

Tags: java, url, javafx

I would like to put an image on a Label, and the codes are:

```
Label userPic = new label();

ImageView userImage = new ImageView(
                             new Image("test/123/headPortrait.png",50.0,50.0,false,false));

userPic.setGraphic(userImage);
```

But it continually throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found.`

And I've tried `file://headPortrait.png`, `file://E:/eclipse/ClassSchedule/headPortrait.png`(the absolute URL). This time the compiler did not throw any exception, but the image still won't show up and the application runs very slowly.

Before I tried to add an image to the label, all of my code had worked perfectly.

Comment: Valid url would be `E:/eclipse/ClassSchedule/headPortrait.png` or `/test/123/headPortrait.png` and not what you wrote

Comment: Possible duplication [JavaFX 8 Image load (Invalid URL or resource not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489402/javafx-8-image-load-invalid-url-or-resource-not-found)

Answer (score -1):

It's not good pratice to put an ImageView into a label. I would recommend to you that you add the ImageView to your scene directly.
To load an Image in the classpath the best way to do that would be using a ResourceStream,

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/headPortrait.png")
```

as example. In this case your image must be in a folder called assets.
Your whole code could look like this:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/headPortrait.png"), 50, 50, false, true));
```

I would recommend to you to set the last boolean flag of the Image constructor to true, because it increases the quality of the image.

Comment: I strongly endorse using an [embedded-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info), but why not leverage the `ContentDisplay` of a `Labeled` control like `Label`?